# Cannot read property 'go' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to `angularjs`

Even though i have specified `$state` in the controller state is not changing it's showing

> angular.js:11594 TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined.

Any answers will be helpful. Thanks if any.

Here is the code:

```
 .controller('ManageCtrl',['$scope','smanageFactory','fileUpload', function($scope,smanageFactory,appConfig,$state,$modal,fileUpload) {


$scope.doFetching= function(studentId, vehicleId){
     smanageFactory.doFetching(studentId,vehicleId).fetch({},function(response){
            $scope.classroom_list =[];
            console.log(response);
            if(response.status == 200 || response.status == 201){
                $state.go('^.list');
                $scope.fetchYearList();
            }
            $scope.response_msg = "successful !!!.";
        },function(response){
            $scope.response_msg1 = "Unsuccessful !!!.";

        });
    };
});
```

[image]

Any answers will be appriciated thanks to all

Comment: if you're going to use array notation, you have to pass all the arguments as strings as well as function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to add the string version of injected arguments in the array.

Right now `appConfig` inside your function is actually `fileUpload`.

Dependencies must be listed in the respective order.

```js
 .controller('ManageCtrl', ['$scope', 'smanageFactory', 'appConfig', '$state', '$modal', 'fileUpload',
   function($scope, smanageFactory, appConfig, $state, $modal, fileUpload) {}
 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No you have not injected the dependency:

```
['$scope','smanageFactory','appConfig', '$state', '$modal', 'fileUpload', 
   function($scope,smanageFactory,appConfig,$state,$modal,fileUpload) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
.controller('ManageCtrl',['$scope','smanageFactory','fileUpload', function($scope,smanageFactory,appConfig,$state,$modal,fileUpload) {

}])
```

Should be this:

```
.controller('ManageCtrl',['$scope', 'smanageFactory', 'appConfig', '$state', '$modal', 'fileUpload', function($scope,smanageFactory,appConfig,$state,$modal,fileUpload) {

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject **$state** as dependency in controller, it will work fine